# Copying all information in sheets to new one

Tags: excel, vba, copy

What I want to do is, to copy all information in all sheets without exception, to the new workbook also created by vba, with exact sheet names.
*the reason is due to after a while excel gives an error when saving the file. 'File was not saved'. So I want to take the information

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Set wb =Workbooks.Add("NewOne.xlsb")
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Name
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy wb.Sheets.Add(Name:=name).Paste
Next
```

Comment: It can be like ThisWorkbook.ws.Name to rename the new sheet in new workbook with exact the same name

Comment: You're overcomplicating probably. Just use `ws.Copy` (no `Paste`, no `wb.Sheets.Add`, no `Set wb = Workbooks.Add)`), which creates a new workbook with a copy of the sheet. Then refer to `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: @BigBen it is unclear, yet. How can ws.Copy create a new workbook. Active Workbook - will excel understand that there is a new workbook created. There are many worksheets...

Comment: From the [`Worksheet.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) docs: If you don't specify either Before or After, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook that contains the copied Worksheet object. The newly created workbook holds the Application.ActiveWorkbook property and contains a single worksheet. The single worksheet retains the Name and CodeName properties of the source worksheet.

Comment: But would not it create as many workbooks as the sheets in old workbook...?

Comment: Ah you only want one new workbook, I see, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use `Worksheets.Copy`(no adding a new workbook, no pasting).

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.copy):

> If you don't specify either *Before* or *After*, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook that contains the copied sheet.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Copy
' Do something with the ActiveWorkbook...
```

Comment: But doyou know the reason, why excel sometimes does not save the workbook.?

Comment: I am not sure without access to the workbook, or to your machine.

Comment: Very nice! I did not know this method...  I thought that it works only for a sheet. I used it when saved to pdf. I tried it on my testing workbook and it crushed. I thought it is a matter of sheets protection but it is not. I tested on another smaller workbook with protected sheets and they are copied keeping their protection. I will analize the crushing reason. Anyhow, the workbook has 233 sheets and maybe a sheets number may exist. Voted up!

Comment: @user16316847 I observed that the sheets are copied with their code module included and you maybe have something wrong in such an event code. It maybe calls a not existing `Sub` from a not existing module and maybe Excel finds inconsistences from this point of view. Do you need the codes in discussion? If not, you can write a piece of code to delete them after copying.

Comment: @FaneDuru, I need them. Today, I have experienced another problem as you described here. A crushed excel workbook with macro and protected sheet. I tried Workbook.Unprotect then ws.copy but it did not even recognize that excel workbook is open...Do you know any other way to repaired broken excel files. I have tried to open with and repair, and tried to copy them with vba, as described it even does not see the excel workbook.

Comment: @FaneDuru - perhaps you want to undelete your answer? Perhaps this is the way to go.

Comment: Undeleted it, but I think that your answer has some potential. Of course, if we are able to understand what's happening... I didn't even imagine that it is possible. No  time now, but I proposed to myself to make some tests, in order to understand in which circumstances this way of copying crushes Excel application and maybe it is something necessary to done. Just for the sake of understanding... This solution is so nice due to its compactness, but I cannot imagine how Microsoft made it possible and did not take care of consequences, at least, explaining the circumstances to be avoided...

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub copySheets()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'add a workbook with only one sheet
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)
 Next
 wb.Sheets(1).delete 'the first existing (empty) sheet
 wb.saveAs FileName:="the workbook full name you need", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```